# Overwrite file if it already exist in flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to overwrite a file's content if it already exists?

For example, with the following, we write "Hello World" and follow by "Sup?". The result of the file is "Sup?o World".

```
File file = ...;
file.writeAsString("Hello World");
file.writeAsString("Sup?");
```

The closest that I find is `FileMode.write` or `FileMode.writeOnly`.

```
/// The file is overwritten if it already exists. The file is created 
/// if it does not already exist.
```

We can rename or delete the old file. But is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

There's an argument that you can pass in to writeAsString(); its file mode.

```
writeAsString(String contents, {FileMode mode = FileMode.writeOnly});
```

It's mentioned in the docs, that writeOnly is,

> Mode for opening a file for writing only. The file is overwritten if it already exists. The file is created if it does not already exist.

[file mode reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/FileMode-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use

```
File file = ...;
final buffer = StringBuffer();

buffer.write('Hello World');
buffer.write('Sup?');

file.writeAsString(buffer.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Though the idea is to use the file as a cache. Imagine `'Hello World` and `Sup?` are from different app sections where memory is not available.

Comment: Well in that case, you need to read the file first using `readAsString` and then use `StringBuffer` on it to append it with your new content, and then again use `writeAsString`.